# Apply a class to the whole page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page with two versions, the normal one with a background white, and i want that when the usser clicks on a button the background changes to black, but the class is only apply to the present page, and if a change from link menu, the new page looses the class of background black, is there a way to make the entire page to change to black, until the button is clicked again to convert it again to white background. here is my code:

```
$('.colorchangera').click(function(){
    $('*').addClass('white');
    $('body').addClass('black');
});
$('.colorchangerb').click(function(){
    $('*').removeClass('white');
    $('body').removeClass('black');
});
```

Comment: Use `localStorage` to store the current `state`

Comment: Could you show me how this is done?

Comment: @dippas It's not the question you pointed as duplicate. Read the question completely.

Comment: How can I give the approach here? you must reopen the question.